# Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.AdaptiveStreaming namespace

Tags: telerik, media-player, rad-controls

I'm new to telerik product. Right now i'm developing a media player.
I want to add a namespace called "Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.AdaptiveStreaming".
I took the guidance for developing the media player from telerik site. (http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#MediaPlayer/SmoothStreaming)
In that also that namespace is used but I don't know where to find that on telerik.
For your reference i have added a screen-shot.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, some dll need to be added
or need to add library file throught LibraryPacketManager. Checkout